# Stacked Container and User Interaction

Tags: ios, events, mapkit, uicontainerview, user-interaction

I have an app where I have a map (MKMapView) and some user interface than could change very often.
I was trying to use storyboard containers : one containing the MKMapView that lies underneath and another on top that should manage the UI.

But doing so, the first container captures the touch events and I cannot move my map.
Is there a way to deal with besides handling touch events directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured that out. When using containers in IB, it actually adds a view for that particular ViewController.
So you can actually call myViewController.view.superView and it returns the view that lies inside the original viewController with the container. Use this to hide or show the container's view!